# How to render human-readable dates in Django?

Tags: python, django, time, django-templates

I am building a Django app where I need to render publication dates.

As of now, dates rendered on my templates look something like this:

> published on February 10, 2020

Can I leverage Django's templating engine to make them more human-readable, like the following for example?

> published an hour ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timesince` like this in your template

```
Published {{your_date_time_field|timesince}} ago
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) for more info